# Visual Studio: Unable to have two folders with binary output and dependencies in installer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer, setup-project

I've created a simple setup project (Visual Studio Installer) and have created two sub folders for the application folder. For each folder I've added the primary output of my project which shall be deployed (because theoretically I want to install the binaries twice ...).

When doing so, I can see, that one sub folder is solving the primary output imediately while the other sub folder does not.

However I can build the setup project and execute the setup successfully. But one sub folder only contains the exe and the exe.config files, while the other is proper and contains also all dependency assemblies.

I use VS 2017 (15.8.7), "Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects"-Extension 0.8.8

What I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you for your hints!
Regards
Patrick

Comment: Which version of VS? (Install projects have changed between versions).

Comment: @Richard: I use VS 2017 (15.8.7), "Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects"-Extension 0.8.8